# dropbox php read file content

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api, readfile

I am creating a simple dropbox app where after authenticating the user, the app is supposed to prompt for some information,  read the content of a txt file. Use ajax for everything after authentication.
so far I have managed to authenticate but when I send the info to the server using ajax I am failing to open the file.
I have the following server side script:

```
<?php
require_once "../app/start.php";

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/config.php';

$regex = $_POST['regex'];
(...)


$accessToken = $_SESSION['accessToken'] ;
$client = new Dropbox\Client($accessToken, $GLOBALS['app_name'], 'UTF-8');
var_dump($client);
// Read File todo.txt

$filename = __DIR__.'/todo/todo.txt';
$f = fopen($filename, "w+b") or die("Unable to open file!");
$fileMetadata = $client->getFile('/todo/todo.txt', $f);
var_dump($fileMetadata);
```

and when I execute it the output is the following:

```
object(Dropbox\Client)#8 (6) {
  ["accessToken":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  string(64) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ["clientIdentifier":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  string(13) "oauth-php/1.0"
  ["userLocale":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["apiHost":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  string(15) "api.dropbox.com"
  ["contentHost":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  string(23) "api-content.dropbox.com"
  ["host"]=>
  object(Dropbox\Host)#5 (3) {
    ["api":"Dropbox\Host":private]=>
    string(15) "api.dropbox.com"
    ["content":"Dropbox\Host":private]=>
    string(23) "api-content.dropbox.com"
    ["web":"Dropbox\Host":private]=>
    string(15) "www.dropbox.com"
  }
}
NULL
```

Where the last `NULL` refers to the content of `$fileMetadata`. **Why is it empty?**

the contnet of `start.php` are the dropbox objects.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$key = "XCV...";
$secret = "DFG...";
$GLOBALS['app_name'] = "oauth-php/1.0";
$GLOBALS['redirectURI'] = "https://oauth.dev/dropbox_finish.php";
$GLOBALS['HomeURI'] = "https://oauth.dev";

$appInfo = new Dropbox\AppInfo($key, $secret);
$csrfTokenStore = new Dropbox\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');
$webAuth = new Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo, $GLOBALS['app_name'], $GLOBALS['redirectURI'], $csrfTokenStore);
```

**Edit:** in the local files I have a directory called `web`, where the files executed are. the there is as well a folder (inside `web`) called `todo` and the file `todo.txt` it is inside. `__DIR__` refers to inside the `web` directory that i have mentioned.

In Dropbox i have a direcotry called `todo` with `todo.txt` inside.

**Edit2:** adding the rest of the code.
`index.php` contains:

```
<?php 
include_once __DIR__.'/../app/start.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../app/dropbox_auth.php';
```

Then `dropbox_auth.php` has the following code:

```
$authURL = $webAuth->start();
header("Location: $authURL");
```

and finally `dropbox_finish.php`

```
<?php
//session_start();
require_once "../app/start.php";

try {
   list($accessToken, $userId, $urlState) = $webAuth->finish($_GET);
   assert($urlState === null);  // Since we didn't pass anything in start()
}
catch (Dropbox\WebAuthException_BadRequest $ex) {
   error_log("/dropbox-auth-finish: bad request: " . $ex->getMessage());
   // Respond with an HTTP 400 and display error page...
}
//review
catch (Dropbox\WebAuthException_BadState $ex) {
   // Auth session expired.  Restart the auth process.
   header('Location: '.$GLOBALS['HomeURI']);
}
catch (Dropbox\WebAuthException_Csrf $ex) {
   error_log("/dropbox-auth-finish: CSRF mismatch: " . $ex->getMessage());
   // Respond with HTTP 403 and display error page...
}
catch (Dropbox\WebAuthException_NotApproved $ex) {
   error_log("/dropbox-auth-finish: not approved: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
catch (Dropbox\WebAuthException_Provider $ex) {
   error_log("/dropbox-auth-finish: error redirect from Dropbox: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
catch (Dropbox\Exception $ex) {
   error_log("/dropbox-auth-finish: error communicating with Dropbox API: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$client = new Dropbox\Client($accessToken, $GLOBALS['app_name'], 'UTF-8');
$_SESSION['accessToken'] = $accessToken;

$_SESSION['client_object'] = $client;

{... here I load an HTML form that uses AJAX send to `insert.php`}
```

Comment: are you sure the `todo/todo.txt` file exists?

Comment: Is it inside `__DIR__` or a top level file?

Comment: Please check out the new edit where I have added some information about your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cant write a comment right now.

Try to get the folder/file list by calling $client->getMetadataWithChildren('/todo/') and check if $f is a valid FilePointerRessource :)

Comment: Thank you. The response is `NULL` even when the folder exists. I have also tried with the `/` dir and it says there is nothing there even when there are a few files and the todo directory. this is the response: `Array
(
    [hash] => 4177b1e8a3e90f5dd949c91de497c876
    [thumb_exists] => 
    [bytes] => 0
    [path] => /
    [is_dir] => 1
    [icon] => folder
    [root] => app_folder
    [contents] => Array
        (
        )

    [size] => 0 bytes
)` Maybe I am overlooking something before?

Comment: I am a little bit confused right now since the dropbox documentation says that the user have to approve that the application is allowed to have access to the dropbox account. Did approve that with your code? And in addition the documentation is only for oAuth2 so where did you get your snippet so far :)

[Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php)

Comment: Please check out the Edit2 part.

Comment: Okay thnx, do you get the account information if you call $client-> getAccountInfo() ? It looks like there is something wrong with the token or the auth process

Comment: It return an array with the following: `Array
(
    [referral_link] => https://db.tt/vc7UZnyV
    [display_name] => Abel
    [uid] => 426010874
    [locale] => en
    [email_verified] => 1
    [team] => 
    [quota_info] => Array
        (
            [datastores] => 0
            [shared] => 0
            [quota] => 2147483648
            [normal] => 692380
        )
    [is_paired] => 
    [country] => BW
    [name_details] => Array
        (
            [familiar_name] => Abel
            [surname] => G..
            [given_name] => Abel
        )
    [email] => abel@xxxx.com
)`

Comment: It looks like your app has "app folder" permission, so you should see the files inside `Dropbox/Apps/<your app name>`.

Comment: Thank you guys it works, It was the permits issue. I have marked your comments as useful, but apart from that I do not know what to do.